# Tap on table row push a new view

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a table . When I click on a table row I want to push a new view . I know that there in navigationController and how to push it , but I want to use such code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
// Navigation logic -- create and push a new view controller

    TasksViewController *tasks = [[TasksViewController  alloc] 
                    initWithNibName:@"Tasks" 
                    bundle:nil];

    LoginAppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [delegate.window addSubview:[tasks view]];
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];        
}
```

The TaskViewCOntroller is a view I want to push like this. When I try to execute this i have an exception like this:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-1448.89/UITableView.m:5678
2011-09-16 12:26:41.118 LeoAction[1149:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00df55a9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00f49313 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00dadef8 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 136
    3   Foundation                          0x000e03bb -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 116
    4   UIKit                               0x0035ac91 -[UITableView(UITableViewInternal) _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:] + 883
    5   UIKit                               0x003504cc -[UITableView(UITableView
```

I do not know what to do with this exception?

Comment: Please paste the code of your cellForRowAtIndexPath function.

Comment: Code of that function from `TasksViewController`

Comment: - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
 static NSString *cellID=@"customCell";
 CustomCell *cell=(CustomCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];
 
 if(cell == nil)
 {
  NSArray *nibObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:nil options:nil];
  for(id currentObject in nibObjects)
  {
   if([currentObject isKindOfClass:[CustomCell class]])
   {
    cell = (CustomCell*)currentObject;
   }
  }
 }
 cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
 [cell.textLabel sizeToFit];
 return cell;
}

Comment: What happens if you temporary comment out this line :     [self.view removeFromSuperview

Answer (score 2):

The exception is telling you that you have a problem in the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method. It sounds like you are not providing a proper return path for every instance of the method being called.

Check that at the end of this method you have something like `return cell;`.

As for your navigation, you should do something like:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:tasks animated:YES];
```

`UIViewController` defines the navigation controller for you, so pushing a new one is as easy as instantiating it and calling the above method.


**EDIT**

With regards to the navigation controller - when you setup your top level table view controller, you need it to be owned by a UINavigationController. I'll assume that you're working with Interface Builder for simplicity.

In your `MainWindow.xib`, drag in a Navigation Controller object. Expand its disclosure arrow, and you'll see that it contains a navigation bar, and a root view controller. Select this root view controller and in the identity inspector, change its class to your custom table view controller, and in the attributes inspector change its NIB Name field to the appropriate nib. Hook up your navigation controller to the App Delegate object as required.

You should then find that you can use the `pushViewController:animated:` method for `self.navigationController` from within `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I did it like you propose, but nothing happened? I have no navigationController I do my navigation like with window.pushView like in my question above.

Comment: The exception is gone but like this nothing happened?

Comment: @Petko: When you add your top level table view controller (the one containing the code you posted), you need to make sure that it is the root view controller of a navigation controller. I'll edit my question again and give more detail.

Comment: :I have the pointers you mentioned but they do not appear here. SO the code is fine.

Comment: It worked like window pushView . THe problem was in TaskViewController view because there is anothet table and I do not provide a method cellForRowAtIndexPath to return cell.

Comment: i do it like you propose in your edit but it not worked at all.

Comment: @Petko: I can't solve a problem for your without some indication of what's not working - any errors/warnings? If it's crashing, where is it crashing, and with what exception?

Answer (score -1):

You should push it like this:

`[self.navigationController pushViewController:taskViewController animated:YES];`

Comment: Francisco but i have no navigation Controller at all?

Answer (score -1):

U can Push Like Bellow

```
TasksViewController *tasks = [[TasksViewController  alloc] 
                initWithNibName:@"Tasks" 
                bundle:nil];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:tasks animated:YES];
[tasks release];
```